# How to display a centered background of fixed width

Tags: html, css, background, background-image

I have [web pages](http://preferans.de/user.php?id=DE10470) with a boring white background and all their contents (the website logo and several google charts) are of the fixed width **700px** and centered:

```
    h1,h2,h3,p,div,form { 
    text-align: center; 
}
```

I'd like to add a vertically-tiled png image underneath (just a stripe of **1px** height), which would display a fixed width **800px** of white and the rest should be some other color (like red in the example below) or gradient and should grow 
 with the page width:

[image]

How do you do it best (i.e. most reliable and for most browsers) with CSS or HTML?

Comment: What do you mean by vertically-tilted? You want to make a gradient from white to red as in the image above?

Comment: No, I meant tiled - like a "tile"  - 1px-high stripe which is repeated again and again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to put your content into a container of 800px in order to achieve both, the red or gradient background **and** the striped PNG effect. So all your content would then go into a `.container` div and your styles would be:

```
body{
   background:#ff0000;
}

.container{
    width:800px;
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;
    background:url('/path/to/image/image.png') repeat 0 0;
}
```

So all your content which currently appears in the `body` tag, will have to be placed in the `.container` div tag like so:

```
<body>
    <div class='container'>
        <p></p>
        <h3></h3>
        .....
    </div>
</body>
```

Ideally, if you're targeting a minimum screen resolution of 800 x 600, your `.container` width should be lesser than 800 to avoid the horizontal scrollbar.

You might also find the links below useful in trying to create both, cross-browser gradients and the PNG:

1. Stripe Generator - http://www.stripegenerator.com/
2. CSS gradient creator - http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

The gradient creator above creates gradients using CSS and also has support for IE. In IE however, since the gradients are created using IE filters, it tends to cut any content hidden inside it, instead of allowing it to overflow. You can always also just use an image to create the gradient.

You might also want to consider using CSS PIE, for IE compatibility - http://css3pie.com/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a **1px height image** as the backgound, find the below code

```
/*CSS*/
 body
 {background:#ff0000;}

 .main
 {
  text-align:center; 
  width:800px; 
  background-image:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNBYu.png');
  background-repeat:y-repeat;
  background-position:center;
  min-height:300px;
 }

/*HTML*/
<body>
<div align="center">
  <div class="main">
     Your Content Goes Here       
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

You can see the result as follows.... (Here I'm repeating the 1px height image vertically, so you can see your background is filled with the image)

[image]

or [Click here to See the Result](http://jsfiddle.net/Hariharan/UQXPs/embedded/result/)

Hope this help you !! Any other questions on top of this, pls do comment !